# NodeJS class with Promise in method

Tags: node.js

I am starting with NodeJS, been writing some code for a couple days. Right now I am creating a new Winston Transport, in order to use MSSQL or OracleDB as the log destination.

I decided to create a DB class to manage connections, inserts, etc to the DB.

My idea is to declare a connection (null) in the constructor, and then have methods to create the connection, insert, etc.

However, as connecting is async, and Winston transport calls the log method, I need to create the connection, make the insert and close (or leave open the connection).

So I went with this:

```
class db {

    constructor(){
        this.connection = null;
    }

    connect(){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            if (this.connection == null){
                if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){

                    const dbOptions = {
                        user: config.Logging.DB.user,
                        password: config.Logging.DB.password,
                        server: config.Logging.DB.mssql.server,
                        database: config.Logging.DB.mssql.database,
                        options: {
                            encrypt: config.Logging.DB.encrypt
                        }
                    };

                    this.connection = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbOptions, err => {
                        if (err) reject('Can\'t establish a DB connection.');
                        this.connection.connect(err => {
                            if (err) reject(err);
                            resolve();
                        });
                    });

                }
            }else{
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }

    insert(query){
        if (config.Logging.DB.type == 'mssql'){
            this.connection.request().query(query, err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

My idea is to create a db class instance upon starting the app, and then use that open connection to make any inserts (each time winston calls the log method), like this:

const db = require('./functions/db');
const db_instance = new db();

```
//Custom DB transport
class DBTransport extends Transport {
    constructor(opts){
        super(opts);
        //db.getConnection();
    }

    log(info, callback) {

        //write
        db_instance.connect().then(()=>{
            db_instance.insert(`insert into logs (message) values ("${info.message}")`);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

        callback();
    }

}
```

But this isn't working at all. First of all I get an error as in the db class connect method I am trying to access 'this.connection' inside a the promise and I am not being able to.

And I also want to keep the connection open, as winston may call the log method lots of times (I have a process that will call the log method over 5K times).

I did try using some of the available winston-mssql transports out there... but they are all updated, and not working with the current version of winston.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save the promise outside of your connect function and return that memoized promise each time like this:

```
class DBTransport {
  connect() {
    if (!this._pool) {
      // Memoize (cache) the connection so you don't have to remake it every time
      this._pool = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const pool = new mssql.ConnectionPool(dbOptions);
        return pool.connect().then(function() {
          return pool;
        });
      });
    }
    return this._pool;
  }
  insert(query) {
    // Always refetch your connection
    return this.connect().then(function(pool) {
      return pool.request().query(query);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, but I am getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection."

Comment: Adding some error handling, I noticed that I get an error in the insert: Connection is closed. Weird, as I open the connection as you suggested above.

Comment: Hmmm 2 returns in each function? As it is it's throwing me errors everywhere :(

Comment: The returns are each inside their own functions.

Comment: I updated my example to not use arrow functions so you can read it better.

Comment: There's an issue with that tho. The insert always tries to "connect", regardless if it is connected or not. Only solution I found was to get the connection, and in its data you get a isconnected property, reading that data you can decide if connect it or not. It's not ideal IMO.

Comment: It doesn't actually connect more than once. At the end of the connect() function, it saves the promise that it created to `this._pool`, so on the next call to `this.connect()`, the `if` gets skipped, so it just returns the promise that you already made last time, which resolves the `pool` that you already created.

Comment: Oh! I don't know what I was doing wrong. But it works. And far cleaner than my solution... bravo!

Comment: Oh! I thought it worked.. but it's not inserting anything in the DB, not any error either..

Comment: Is there any output in the `then` or `catch` downstream from here?

Comment: Are you missing any of the `return`s? If they aren't all there, that could happen.